# How to query only specific properties of RealmObject?

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

For example, I have object:

```
public class person : RealmObject { 
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string secondname { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
}
```

How to make query that will give me only list of addresses or firstnames + secondnames?

Or firstname and age.

Comment: Query? Do you have a list of objects in memory and you want to query this  list? Do you want to fecth this data from a database?

Comment: From Realm database, of course.

Comment: How do you access your database? Using ADO.NET or an ORM? If you use an ORM, which ORM you use ?

Comment: Not sure. I just use Realm library and this syntax: https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/

Comment: If you have ever used LINQ it's pretty straightforward how you can fetch your data using Realm. Please see my answer. If you haven't, despite the fact that you will understand by reading the code (simplicity and readability of LINQ), I encourage you to read about LINQ since it's a part of C# that any C# developer should have under his/her belt. It saves lifes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `Select` is not currently supported...

As long as your `Select` is projecting a `RealmObject`, it is supported, but you are asking for a projection that changes the type from `RealmObject` to another type and that is not support:

- https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/916

If you really need to break object's connection to the Realm database, you can take your base query to a list (`.ToList`) and *then* perform a Select projection on the result:

```
realm.All<Dog>().ToList().Select(dog => dog.Name);
```

#### Update:

For your first + second name question, I would add that as a read-only property on your RealmObject subclass. Since that property has a custom setter/getter it will not be persisted in the Realm data store.

```
public class person : RealmObject
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string secondname { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }

    public string name { get { return firstname + " " + secondname; } }
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var realm = Realms.Realm.GetInstance("stackoverflow.db");
var me = new person() { firstname = "Sushi", secondname = "Hangover", age = 99, address = "Local sushi bar" };
realm.Write(() => realm.Add<person>(me));
var user = realm.All<person>().Where((person p) => p.firstname == "Sushi" && p.secondname == "Hangover").FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine($"{user.name} is {user.age} years old and is currently at {user.address}");
```

Output:

```
Sushi Hangover is 99 years old and is currently at Local sushi bar
```

Update2:

If you are looking to iterate through a returned collection of RealmObjects:

```
var users = realm.All<person>().Where((person p) => p.age < 40);
Console.WriteLine($"There are {users.Count()} users under 40 years of age and they are located at:");
foreach (var user in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{user.firstname} is currently at {user.address}");
}
```

Comment: But what way is most optimal in sense of performance? Isn't `.ToList` before `Select` will lead to excess operations?

Comment: In terms of performance, use the resulting `RealmObject`. It is *live* and connected to the Realm database and there is *no penalty* in retrieving all the properties of the Realm mapped object. Taking it to a List and then projecting an object with less properties is a performance hit (memory and speed), BUT sometimes you might want to break that *live* connection and `ToList` will do that.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! My case is pretty memory sensitive so better to consider right way.

Comment: But what do you mean telling that I project `RealmObject` to an another type? Isn't it right way to declare `RealmObject`?

Comment: The `RealmObject` is ***mapped*** to the Realm-core `C++` code/object during the build process, a Fody' Weaving build task, and thus directly using the RealmObject will be the fastest.

Comment: @InfernumDeus When you use a Linq `Select` to transform a base object to something, that is a *Select projection*, in your question, retrieving *only* a `first name` would be a projection of an IEnumerable of RealmObjects to an IEnumerable of strings

Comment: Can you please add to the answer example of direct usage of the RealmObject?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Now I see my question was unclear (pretty bad object example). I need to get several properties of object separately. Added better example of what I want to the question - firstname + age. Basically, I need to get several properties of each "person" to do something different with each of properties.

Comment: Interesting example, but not really. Pointed in previous comment what I actually need.

Comment: In my actual project I have `RealmObject` with several numerical properties used diverently in some calculations.

Comment: @InfernumDeus I added a RealmResult iteration.... if you are still not clear of the RealmObject property access and have a concrete example of what you are trying to do, please open a new question to avoid all these comments, thanks!

Comment: Now I see. Just though it whould be faster to use analogue of SQL: `SELECT firstname, age FROM person`. But your way looks much better.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate all your effort.

Comment: @InfernumDeus Ahh, I see now, in using Realm just think in terms of Object properties and enumerations as it is an **ORM**. No problem, glad I could help...

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the below:

```
var realm = Realm.GetInstance();

var addresses = realm.All<person>()
                     .ToList()
                     .Select(person => person.address)
                     .ToList();

var firstAndSecondNames = realm.All<person>()
                               .ToList()
                               .Select(person => new
                               {
                                   FirstName = person.firstName,
                                   SecondName = person.secondName
                               })
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: FYI: You would need to take the `RealmObject`/`RealmResult` query to a list first and then perform the Select projection.

Comment: @SushiHangover ty for the info, I wans't aware of this.